# Targeting named outlet via routerLink adds extraneous "/"

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular2-routing, router, outlet

I'm trying to launch a modal in my app via routing. Everything seems to work except that an extra slash is added to the URL that prevents it from resolving. The Url should look like this (and it works if I enter it manually)...

```
/accounts(modal:accounts/1/edit)
```

but i'm getting this instead (notice the slash between the base url and outlet target)...

```
/accounts/(modal:accounts/1/edit)
```

The base tag is set...

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>myApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

Here's my routing config (accounts-routing.module.ts)

```
const ACCOUNT_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'accounts',
    component: AccountsIndexComponent
  },{
    path: 'accounts/new',
    component: AccountsNewComponent
  },{
    path: 'accounts/:id',
    component: AccountsShowComponent
  },{
    path: 'accounts/:id/edit',
    component: AccountsEditComponent,
    outlet: 'modal'
  }
];
```

And outlet (app.component.html)

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>
```

And the link...

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { modal: ['accounts', account.id, 'edit'] } }]">Edit</a>
```

What am I missing? The project was created using `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.26` and `angular@2.4.6` and `angular-router@3.4.6` are installed.

FWIW, here's a screenshot of the logs...

[image: failed routing attempt]

Comment: Have you added `<base href="/">` to the `index.html`-file?

Comment: yup, there is a `<base href="/">` tag

Comment: As the first child of the `<head>`-tag? I think your problem might be with how relate paths are resolved.

Comment: Yes, it's in the `<head>` tag. The HTML was generated by angular-cli and I haven't touched it. I tried to moving it to be the first child of the `<head>` but that didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: routerLink is relative to where it is used (/accounts/ if inside of that component and /accounts if outside of it). Try a relative path: `<a [routerLink]="['../', { outlets: { modal: ['accounts', account.id, 'edit'] } }]">`

Comment: I tried the relative path you suggested and it gives me a route of `//(modal:accounts/1/edit)`. So, i tried `['', { outlets: { modal: ['accounts', account.id, 'edit'] } }]` and that works! That doesn't feel like a good solution to me though?

Comment: Nah, it should be fine. Now you are using an absolute path. Did you try `./`?

Comment: I did, `./` gives me the same path i was seeing initially. Thx for the help!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The fix was to define an empty relative path on the link. Thanks to @unitario for pointing me in the right direction!

```
<a [routerLink]="['', { outlets: { modal: ['accounts', account.id, 'edit'] } }]">Edit</a>
```

Comment: In our application we have an authentication modal that can open over any view so any initial path caused issues, either by loosing the current route or by adding extra slash. This solved the issue, Thank you! the only thing added is queryParamsHandling="merge" to facilitate passing parameters to the modal and the underlying view              `<a [routerLink]="['', {outlets: {'modal': ['auth']}}]" [queryParams]="{login: true}" class="auth-link log-in" queryParamsHandling="merge">Log in</a>`