# angular router outlet fails with routerLink outside AppComponent

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I use angular 5.2.0 and I navigated to:

```
/page/28/1
```

corresponding to:

```
{path: 'page/:albumId/:pageNo', component: AlbumPageComponent}
```

The AlbumPageComponent html contains:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['login'] } }]">
```

corresponding to:

```
{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'popup'}
```

and supposed to be used with `<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>` placed into the classical *app.component.html* (it's a simple angular cli generated project).

This doesn't work because the wrong formed path as I noticed it in console:

```
NavigationStart(id: 3, url: '/page/28/1/(popup:login)')
```

But does work when used this way:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="" (click)="goToLogin()">
```

with AlbumPageComponent having:

```
goToLogin() {
  this.router.navigate([{outlets: {popup: ['login']}}]);
}
```

The correct path then is formed:

```
NavigationStart {id: 3, url: "/page/28/1(popup:login)"}
```

Please be aware that the routing command is the same for both situations, meaning:

```
[{outlets: {popup: ['login']}}]
```

Q: what is wrong with the `routerLink` approach? how could it be fixed?

PS: I also use: *"baseHref": "/albums/"* in *.angular-cli.json* though I see no reason for this to be an issue

**EDIT**

The same happens to the example from https://angular.io/guide/router#wrap-up-and-final-app. In order to replicate you'll have to copy the `<a/>` for *Contact* to CrisisCenterComponent html. This way, and also as I do, one would use `[routerLink]` approach inside a different component than AppComponent. Directly used in AppComponent html the `[routerLink]` approach works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this format:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['', { outlets: { popup: ['login'] } }]">
```

Actually, taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098257/6528560

Comment: Indeed it’s the same problem. Anyway I would let this post too because both titles seems to me relevant for the issue - that’s why I couldn’t find the solution here in the first place.